# 16.04.2 LTS wifi drops with kernel 4.10-27, but OK with kernel 4.8.0-58

Tags: 16.04, wireless, realtek-wireless

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my ASUS X555L. I upgrade the OS when prompted to do so. The last upgrade took the kernel from 4.8.0-58 to 4.10.0-27. Since then my wifi drops the connection when connected to the BBC's iplayer service, which streams video to my laptop. It is OK when I select the GRUB option to boot from the previous kernel.

The wifi configuration as produced by a ***sudo lshw -C network*** is:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: b0:c0:90:3b:d8:f3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.10.0-27-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:51 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b2000000-b2003fff
```

If I load the 4.8 kernel its is much the same, apart from the driverversion being 4.8.0-58-generic.

I am asking if anyone else has encountered such a problem and what I might do to try and track down the cause of the error? For example which log might I look in?

**Also**
after the wifi is dropped, the command
***sudo service network-manager restart*** does not turn on the wifi again

**More Info**:
My Ubuntu version is actually 16.04.2 LTS which I have enabled the [hardware enablement stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

Comment: I also was having a very similar problem with practically the same kernel versions, so I did  the most logical thing and asked the question on askbuntu. The answers I received basically said that "tried" and "tested" code (older kernel versions), sometimes is more stable. Anyways, I am not currently sure how to report this kind of problem.

Comment: I had similar problems with kernel version above 4.10. (also asus laptop, also Realtek Semiconductor Co).
Right now I'm booting 4.8.0-36-generic and it works fine, again.
Maybe this one might work for you, too.