# WiFi automatically disconnects in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, wifi-direct

I am new to Ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in dual boot with Windows. Everything is working fine in Windows. However, in Ubuntu, WiFi gets disconnected automatically.

Below are the outputs for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` and `iwconfig`

```
prince@devilDevice:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:a814]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ae


prince@devilDevice:~$ iwconfig
enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"NETGEAR34"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 20:E5:2A:E4:CA:74   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:77   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

**wireless card details**

```
prince@devilDevice:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for prince: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 54:e1:ad:82:09:ce
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:279 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:94104000-94104fff memory:94100000-94103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: 60:14:b3:aa:70:b9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.10.0-28-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:283 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94000000-94003fff
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a 4.10 kernel [see this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940342/16-04-2-lts-wifi-drops-with-kernel-4-10-27-but-ok-with-kernel-4-8-0-58) and the same wifi adapter.

Perhaps installing an older 4.8 kernel might help if you currently have a 4.10.x kernel in your machine.

Comment: Can you tell mehow to install an older kernel version ? I am current running `4.10.0.38-generic`